# pymssql returns different charset on Azure/Windows than on Mac

Tags: python, azure, character-encoding, pymssql

I have an sql server database hosted on Azure. I have put a string in the database with smart quotes('“test”'). I can connect to it and run a simple query:

```
import pymssql
import json

conn = pymssql.connect(
    server='coconut.database.windows.net',
    user='kingfish@coconut',
    password='********',
    database='coconut',
    charset='UTF-8',
)

sql = """
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id = '548a72cc-f584-7e21-2725-fe4dd594982f'
"""
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
json.dumps(row[3])
```

When I run this query on my Mac (macOS 10.11.6, Python 3.4.4, pymssql 2.1.3) I get back the string:

```
"\u201ctest\u201d"
```

This is correctly interpreted as smart quotes and displays properly.

When I run this query on an Azure web deployment (Python 3.4, Azure App service) I get back a different (and incorrect) encoding for that same string:

```
"\u0093test\u0094"
```

I specified the charset as 'UTF-8' on the pymssql connection. Why does the Windows/Azure environment get back a different charset?

(note: I have put the pre-built binary pymssql-2.1.3-cp34-none-win32.whl in the wheelhouse of my project repo on Azure. This is the same as the pymssql pre-built binary pymssql-2.1.3-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl on PyPI only I had to rename the 'cp34m' to 'none' to convince pip to install it.)

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I think it seems that the issue was caused by the default charset encoding of the SQL Database on Azure. For verifing my thought, I did some testing below in Python 3.

The default charset encoding of SQL Database on Azure is [Windows-1252 (CP-1252)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

> [SQL Server Collation Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-general-limitations/#sql-server-collation-support)
>   The default database collation used by Microsoft Azure SQL Database is SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS, where LATIN1_GENERAL is English (United States), **CP1 is code page 1252**, CI is case-insensitive, and AS is accent-sensitive. It is not possible to alter the collation for V12 databases. For more information about how to set the collation, see COLLATE (Transact-SQL).

```
>>> u"\u201c".encode('cp1252')
b'\x93'
>>> u"\u201d".encode('cp1252')
b'\x94'
```

As the code above shown, the `\u0093` & `\u0094` can be got via encode `\u201c` & `\u201d`.

And,

```
>>> u"\u0093".encode('utf-8')
b'\xc2\x93'
>>> u"\u0093".encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')[1]
'“'     # It's `\u201c`
>>> u"\u201c" == u"\u0093".encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')[1]
True
```

So I think the charset encoding of your current SQL Database for data storage is `Latin-1`, not `UTF-8`, when you created the SQL Database, as the figure below, the default property `Collation` on Azure portal is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Please try to use the other collation support `UTF-8` instead of the default one.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I am using the default collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS . When I run "sys.stdin.encoding" on my Mac I get "utf-8" and on Azure I get "cp1252". I wonder if the default python character encoding is determining the unicode characters being used. Only I can not figure out how to do "chcp 65001" on Azure before it launches Python ...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up recasting the column type from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR. This solved my problem, characters are correctly interpreted, regardless of platform.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your sharing.